# Why does var cause a type variance error where val compiles in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, variance

```
scala> case class Data[+T](val value:T=null)
defined class Data

scala> val foo=Data[ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]]]()
foo: Data[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]]] = Data(null)

scala> foo.value+=Data[String]()
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 33 elided
```

I would like to have a Data class that is instantiated either as Data[String], Data[ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]]] or Data[Map[String,Data[Any]]]. In the above example I try to instantiate it as Data[ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]]] and add a Data[String] to its arraybuffer. Of course I get a null pointer exception because value is null. But the point of this example that it at least compiles and runs.

Now, in the Data constructor I would like to instantiate value as either a Data[String], an ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]] or Map[String,Data[Any]] depending on the type of the initially null value returned by the getClass method. However for this I need value to be a var, so that I can modify it after examining the type of its null value.

However I get this error:

```
scala> case class Data[+T](var value:T=null)
<console>:11: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value value_=
       case class Data[+T](var value:T=null)
```

Comment: Any reason you use a `null` over an `Option`?

Comment: Don't use `null` in Scala. It really only exists for interoperability with Java. Use `Option` instead. And making a case class mutable is bad practice; keep it immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your `Data` invariant in `T`. Just remove the `+`:  `Data[T]` - this should compile.
Better yet, rethink your design to get rid of nulls and mutable variables - they both smell.

**Edit**: after reading your comments, I understand better what you are trying to do. Consider something like this for example as one of the options.

```
sealed trait Node 
case class ListNode(list: Seq[Node]) extends Node
case class MapNode(map: Map[String, Node]) extends Node
case class LeafNode(data: String) extends Node
```

Now you can parse your document with something like (this is "pseudocode", adjust it to whatever xml-parsing library you are using):

```
def parseNode(tag: XMLTag): Node = tag.tagType match {
   case LIST => 
      val subNodes = tag.getNestedTags.map(parseNode)
      ListNode(subNodes)
   case MAP => 
      val subNodes = tag.getNestedTags.map { tag => 
        tag.name -> parseNode(tag) 
      }
      MapNode(subNodes.toMap)
   case _ =>  
      LeafNode(tag.text)
}
```

Comment: It does not compile with T, see my answer.

Comment: Sure, it does: `scala> case class Data[T](var value:T=null)
defined class Data`

Comment: I mean the whole program does not compile. If I want to use it in a way I described in the question then I need +T. I can't add Data[String] to an ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]] otherwise. The arraybuffer has to be able to contain mixed kinds of Data, some of its elements will be Data[String], some Data[ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]] etc.

Comment: Oh, I see... This is abusing the language even more than I initially thought :) Are you coming from perl programming background by some chance?

Comment: How do you know this? Actually I did code in Perl earlier.

Comment: @sbtpr It's just that you are still coding in perl, as far as I can tell from your question and comments. You are using Scala syntax, but still sticking with perl concepts, it's very apparent, and that's how I was able to tell.

Comment: Now: my problem is to parse an XML document which encodes a tree of nodes, some of which are lists of nodes, some of which are maps from string to node, leaf nodes being strings. In Data I try to describe a node of this tree. How do you build up this structure of nodes in the Scala way instead of the Perl way?

Comment: @sbtpr Three different classes, extending a common trait.

Answer (score 3):

http://like-a-boss.net/2012/09/17/variance-in-scala.html#variance_and_type_safety

> Variance and type safety
>
> When defining a generic class with a var field we can get compile time errors:

```
scala> class Invariant[T](var t: T)
defined class Invariant

scala> class Covariant[+T](var t: T)
<console>:7: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value t_=
      class Covariant[+T](var t: T)
            ^

scala> class Contravariant[-T](var t: T)
<console>:7: error: contravariant type T occurs in covariant position in type => T of method t
      class Contravariant[-T](var t: T)
```

> Let’s break it down a little. Why doesn’t the compiler allow getters in the Covariant class?

```
scala> abstract trait Covariant[+T] {
    |   def take(t: T): Unit
    | }
<console>:8: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value t
        def take(t: T): Unit
                  ^

scala> abstract trait Contravariant[-T] {
    |   def take(t: T): Unit
    | }
defined trait Contravariant
```

> Why? Let’s think about usages of covariance let’s say that we have a class:

```
class Printer[+T] {
    |    def print(t: T): Unit = ???
    | }
<console>:8: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value t
          def print(t: T): Unit = ???
```

> If the print method can print Dogs does it make sense (in general) that it should also print Animals? Maybe sometimes but in the general sense if we want to generalize the Printer class we should use contravariance. The compiler is smart enough to check this type of usage for us.
>
> Let’s think about the second use case: returning a generic parameter:

```
scala> class Create[-T] {
    |   def create: T = ???
    | }
<console>:8: error: contravariant type T occurs in covariant position in type => T of method create
        def create: T = ???
```

> And again - does it make sense that Create should generalize by contravariance? If Create returns instances of the Animal class should we be able to use it in every place that expects Create[Dog]? The scala compiler is smart enough that it explodes in our face if we try it.

Comment: How can I make my example work then? Currently I have a single Data class, which has var fields String, ArrayBuffer[Data] and Map[String,Data] and I construct it by passing its type as a String parameter ( like Data("String"). This does not seem to be too elegant.

Comment: @sbtpr Why don't you construct the `Data` class when you have the data? Why do you need the `var`?

Comment: I can do this, but then I have to explicitly initialize value upon construction, which seems a bit too verbose. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can make it work this way:

```
package data

case class Data[+T](val value:T)
{
    println(value.getClass)
}
```

This way I have to explicitly initialize value from the constructor. Nothing wrong with this, just I find it a bit too verbose.

```
import data.Data

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object Run extends App
{

    val a=Data[ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]]](ArrayBuffer[Data[Any]]())

    a.value+=Data[String]("bar")

    println(a.value)

    val m=Data[Map[String,Data[Any]]](Map[String,Data[Any]]())

    m.value+=("foo"->Data[String]("bar"))

    println(m.value)

}
```

This prints:

```
class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
class java.lang.String
ArrayBuffer(Data(bar))
class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
class java.lang.String
Map(foo -> Data(bar))
```

The program only compiles with Data having +T type parameter, otherwise I get the error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : data.Data[String]
[error]  required: data.Data[Any]
[error] Note: String <: Any, but class Data is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]         a.value+=Data[String]("bar")
```